# What does the standard thread.start() return in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

What does the Python `Thread.start()` method return?

I can't seem to find this in the Python docs.
(I also think I miss something obvious from them because the return value for methods is seldom described.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns nothing interesting, `None`.

Comment: I'd upvote but I can't in 9 hours. :) Can I take it that whenever the Python docs just don't mention return value, it is `None`?

Comment: That is generally a pretty safe assumption, but it is trivially testable, so when you're not sure, try it out!